# Capacitance - Voltage characteristic diagram in a Schottky diode

Tags: voltage, capacitance, diagram, schottky

I 've searched the web for that diagram with no satisfactory result. Does a schottky diode has capacitance or not because of very tiny depletion (almost none) zone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schottky diodes have pretty constant reverse capacitance with reverse voltage changes. There is usually only about a 2:1 change in C with quite large changes in Vr. I've used a BAT41 recently and this is the graph: -

[image]

I would also suggest that most commonly used schottky diodes do possess this graph in their respective data sheets so if you have one particular device in mind take a look.

EDIT - I just took a look at a few devices on Farnell and every device's data sheet had a graph of capacitance vs reverse voltage.

Answer (score 1):

OK first I've never looked at the capacitance of a Schottky diode. 
But (in theory) I would expect them to be like an abrupt PN junction and show a capacitance that decreased as the square root of the reverse voltage. (C ~ 1/V^2)

(There is still a doped semiconductor wit ha depletion layer on one side of the junction.)

Here's a [one](http://www.comchiptech.com/cms/UserFiles/CDBM120-G%20Thru934798.%20CDBM1150-G%20RevD.pdf), 
[another](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds30044.pdf), 
[more](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/SS/SS12.pdf)...

I'd have to plot up some points to see how well practice follows theory.

Edit:  The last link from Fairchild does the C-V plot log-log. And so you can see that it sorta goes as 1/V^2.  (Change from 1 V to 100 V is about 1/10.. 200pf to 20 pf.)

Comment: You are right, that it is an abrupt junction.  The lack of capacitance modulation arises from the fact that the Si side can be very heavily doped so the free space region is quite small.  The second effect is that the barrier height is reduced.

Comment: @placeholder, did you look at the last link from fairchild.  For a high voltage diode, the doping can not be too high or else you get avalanche breakdown. (I think)  I'm not sure about the BAT41 that Andy linked to.  Maybe the C is so small that most of it is from the package/leads, with less do to changes in the junction width.

Comment: No I didn't, I was speaking in general terms.  And yes for High voltage devices the doping must decrease.  Your statements are still correct, just don't apply them too broadly ..  ;)  The lead capacitance will be in the pF range so unlikely.